# Using Reactives to Merge Chunked Messages

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, system.reactive

So I'm attempting to use reactives to recompose chunked messages identified by ID and am having a problem terminating the final observable. I have a Message class which consists of Id, Total Size, Payload, Chunk Number and Type and have the following client-side code:

I need to calculate the number of messages to Take at runtime

```
(from messages in
   (from messageArgs in Receive select Serializer.Deserialize<Message>(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageArgs.Message))))
 group messages by messages.Id into grouped select grouped)
.Subscribe(g =>
{
    var cache = new List<Message>();
    g.TakeWhile((int) Math.Ceiling(MaxPayload/g.First().Size) < cache.Count)
      .Subscribe(cache.Add, 
    _ => { /* Rebuild Message Parts From Cache */ });
});
```

First I create a grouped observable filtering messages by their unique ID and then I am trying to cache all messages in each group until I have collected them all, then I sort them and put them together. The above seems to block on g.First().

I need a way to calculate the number to take from the first (or any) of the messages that come through however am having difficulty doing so. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`First` is a blocking operator (how else can it return `T` and not `IObservable<T>`?)

I think using `Scan` (which builds an aggregate over time) could be what you need. Using `Scan`, you can hide the "state" of your message re-construction in a "builder" object.

`MessageBuilder.IsComplete` returns true when all the size of messages it has received reaches `MaxPayload` (or whatever your requirements are). `MessageBuilder.Build()` then returns the reconstructed message.

I've also moved your "message building" code into a `SelectMany`, which keeps the built messages within the monad.

(Apologies for reformatting the code into extension methods, I find it difficult to read/write mixed LINQ syntax)

```
Receive
    .Select(messageArgs => Serializer.Deserialize<Message>(
        new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageArgs.Message))))
    .GroupBy(message => message.Id)
    .SelectMany(group =>
    {
        // Use the builder to "add" message parts to
        return group.Scan(new MessageBuilder(), (builder, messagePart) =>
        {
            builder.AddPart(messagePart);

            return builder;
        })
        .SkipWhile(builder => !builder.IsComplete)
        .Select(builder => builder.Build());
    })
    .Subscribe(OnMessageReceived);
```

Comment: Cool solution, I always forget about GroupBy

Comment: That is indeed a very cool solution, I obviously need to look into the vast range of options available in LINQ. Many thanks